# problem with pip installing numpy × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I got this problem when trying to install `numpy` on my Mac. anyone can help me?! I tried to find many ways but can't work.

> ```
> Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
>   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>   
>   × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
>   │ exit code: 1
>   ╰─> [173 lines of output]
>       Running from numpy source directory.
>       Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
>       Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
>       Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
>       Cythonizing sources
>       INFO: blas_opt_info:
>       INFO: blas_armpl_info:
>       INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
>       INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: blas_mkl_info:
>       INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: blis_info:
>       INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: openblas_info:
>       INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: accelerate_info:
>       INFO:   libraries accelerate not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO: Library accelerate was not found. Ignoring
>       INFO:   libraries veclib not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO: Library veclib was not found. Ignoring
>       INFO:   FOUND:
>       INFO:     extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
>       INFO:     extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
>       INFO:     define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>       INFO:
>       INFO:   FOUND:
>       INFO:     extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
>       INFO:     extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
>       INFO:     define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>       INFO:
>       non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
>       INFO: lapack_opt_info:
>       INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
>       INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
>       INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
>       INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
>       INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO: flame_info:
>       INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib', '/usr/lib']
>       INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
>       INFO:
>       INFO:   FOUND:
>       INFO:     extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
>       INFO:     extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
>       INFO:     define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>       INFO:
>       Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
>       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
> warnings.warn(msg)
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running config_cc
> INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc
> INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
> running build_src
> INFO: build_src
> INFO: building py_modules sources
> creating build
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/distutils
> INFO: building library "npymath" sources
> WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
> WARN: Could not locate executable f95
> WARN: Could not locate executable nagfor
> WARN: Could not locate executable f90
> WARN: Could not locate executable f77
> WARN: Could not locate executable xlf90
> WARN: Could not locate executable xlf
> WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
> WARN: Could not locate executable ifc
> WARN: Could not locate executable g77
> WARN: Could not locate executable g95
> WARN: Could not locate executable pgfortran
> WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath
> INFO: conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
> INFO:   adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath' to
> include_dirs.
> INFO: conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
> INFO: conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
> INFO: None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
> INFO: building library "npyrandom" sources
> INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
> creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray
> INFO: conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
> INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py",
> line 363, in 
> main()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py",
> line 345, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py",
> line 261, in build_wheel
> return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
> line 230, in build_wheel
> return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
> line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
> self.run_setup()
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
> line 267, in run_setup
> super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py",
> line 158, in run_setup
> exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'), locals())
> File "setup.py", line 461, in 
> setup_package()
> File "setup.py", line 453, in setup_package
> setup(**metadata)
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/core.py",
> line 169, in setup
> return old_setup(**new_attr)
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 153, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py",
> line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py",
> line 966, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py",
> line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-40tmvwr1/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 299, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py",
> line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/command/build.py",
> line 61, in run
> old_build.run(self)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py",
> line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py",
> line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py",
> line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",
> line 144, in run
> self.build_sources()
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",
> line 161, in build_sources
> self.build_extension_sources(ext)
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",
> line 318, in build_extension_sources
> sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
> File "/private/var/folders/xw/ckmzfpt11mz8w4xyp06nlgtm0000gn/T/pip-install-60obbqqe/numpy_de5294ff4aaa414fa62c325121beed8e/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py",
> line 378, in generate_sources
> source = func(extension, build_dir)
> File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 502, in generate_config_h
> moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
> File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 50, in check_types
> out = check_types(*a, **kw)
> File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 346, in check_types
> raise SystemError(
> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
> [end of output]
>
> ```
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
>   ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
> Failed to build numpy
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
> ```

I see it normal on my PC but on my Mac is quite different .